# TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

this is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. I'm new to JS and Firebase and I'm currently following a React course, there is a part in which I have to implement Firebase to my "To-do App". But I get this error:

```
ERROR
_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.collection is not a function
TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.collection is not a function
    at Add (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51:55)
    ...
```

This is my firebase.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export default db;
```

And the initial use of db is in my App.js in the Add function in which I'm trying to add to-dos to Firestore.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import db from './firebase';
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase/firestore'; // Importa FieldValue desde 'firebase/firestore', no es necesario importar 'firebase/app'
import './App.css';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import AddBoxOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddBoxOutlined';
import UpdateIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Update';
import DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlineOutlined';

function App() {

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  var today = new Date()
  var dateTime = today.getDate() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getFullYear() + '    ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() + ':' + today.getSeconds()

  const Add = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    db.collection('TodoApp').add({
      TODO: text,
      TIME: dateTime,
      SERVERTIMESTAMP: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    })
      .then(() => {
        setText('')
        alert('Todo added successfully')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert('Error adding todo', error)
      })
  }
```

I've tried to look for similar errors but I can't find a solution yet.

I can post more of the code if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APIs of the Firebase SDK were updated a couple of years ago and changed the syntax of most of the SDK. Read through the [modular SDK upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for details on how to migrate legacy code to the new methods.

In your case, `db` is an instance of the [`Firestore`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestore.md#firestore_class) class. As you can see from the linked API reference there is no `collection()` method on that class. This is because the [SDK switched to a modular syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_) where you call functions for each feature, passing in the object to use as the first argument, followed by any other arguments.

Your current code:

```
import db from './firebase';

// ...

db.collection('TodoApp').add({
  TODO: text,
  TIME: dateTime,
  SERVERTIMESTAMP: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
  .then(() => { /* ... */})
  .catch((err) => { /* ... */})
```

should be rewritten as

```
import db from './firebase';
import { addDoc, collection, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

// ...

const todoColRef = collection(db, 'TodoApp'); // collection used here

addDoc(todoColRef, { // addDoc used here
  TODO: text,
  TIME: dateTime,
  SERVERTIMESTAMP: serverTimestamp() // serverTimestamp used here
})
  .then(() => { /* ... */})
  .catch((err) => { /* ... */})
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it is now working!